How to modify bluetooth read-only property device class in both bt-adapter and hciconfig
In my embedded linux device, I get the following outputs
# hciconfig -a hci0 | grep Class
    Class: 0x022300
    Service Classes: Networking
    Device Class: LAN Access, Uncategorized

# bt-adapter -i | grep Class
    Class: 0x0

I tried to modify the class manually using below:
# hciconfig hci0 class 0x22300

I also tried changing the /etc/bluetooth/main.conf file:
Class = 0x022300

But still bt-adapter shows class as 0x0. Is there a way to modify the bt-adapter device class?
